# Xslt to transform element to array element

Tags: xml, xslt

My business requirement is to transform below input XML into transformed XML.

Input XML is as below

```
<root>   
    <name>football</name>  
    <pageTitle>League</pageTitle>  
    <pageMetaDescription>Inter City League</pageMetaDescription>     
</root>
```

Output Xml that is expected after the XSLT based transformation is

```
<root>  
  <Array>
    <name>name</name>
    <text>football</text>      
    <format>plainText</format>
  </Array>
  <Array>
    <name>pageTitle</name>
    <text>League</text>      
    <format>plainText</format>
  </Array>
  <Array>
    <name>pageMetaDescription</name>
    <text>Inter City League</text>      
    <format>plainText</format>
  </Array>   
</root>
```

In-order to Perform such tranformation I am not able to write XSLT.
Can anyone let me know how to write such XSLT for such requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `I am not able to write XSLT`, but I read it as *my knowledge of XSLT
is too limited and need help how to do it*.
Anyway, you marked this question a.o. with just **XSLT**!

The template matching `root` is quite similar to the *identity teplate*.

But the template matching its child elements is more complicated:

- Start with `Array` opening tag.
- Then write its content including:

  - `name` tag with value equal to the name of the tag (*name()*).
  - `text` tag with value equal to the content of the tag (*.*).
  - `format` tag with content of `plainText`.
- End with `Array` closing tag.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root/*">
    <Array>
      <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></name>
      <text><xsl:value-of select="."/></text>
      <format>plainText</format>
    </Array>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You didn't write it, but if you have other cases of source tags with
*format* other than *plainText* (e.g. *date*), you have to write
other templates (matching these tag names), with respective details
written another way.